# Keep track of synchronization changes

Tags: c#, logging, sql-server-2012, synchronization, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server 2012 storing one shared database over multiple SQL Server CE database clients.

Process is like this:

1. At application start, clients connect to server to get data from the server
2. Clients alter the data (add new rows, modifying or deleting existing rows)
3. Sync' with the server to send the changes

For history record, I am looking for ways to log all this activity in order to keep track of every action for maintenance sake.

How can we manage this?

Comment: You could add an audit table and audit and log activity in your data acces layer on the client, and sync this table up.

Comment: Isn't there something in the synchronization framework that can help to do this without having to do code it all ?
I am keeping your idea in case there is none else.

Comment: Sync framework tracks changes, yes, but it does not log data changes over time

Comment: I see. Will implement your idea then. Thanks for your time sir !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an audit table and audit and log activity in your data acces layer on the client, and sync this table up.